# Spark SQL converting string to timestamp

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Spark SQL and am trying to convert a string to a timestamp in a spark data frame. I have a string that looks like `'2017-08-01T02:26:59.000Z'` in a column called time_string

My code to convert this string to timestamp is

```
CAST (time_string AS Timestamp)
```

But this gives me a timestamp of `2017-07-31 19:26:59`

Why is it changing the time? Is there a way to do this without changing the time?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: try `unix_timestamp` to cast it to TimestampType :)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761586/spark-sql-not-converting-timezone-correctly .

Comment: In `Spark 2.3.2` (`emr-5.19.0`), I can confirm the `CAST(time_string AS timestamp)` worked without a glitch (didn't *change the time*)

Answer (score 28):

You could use [unix_timestamp](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) function to convert the utc formatted date to timestamp

```
val df2 = Seq(("a3fac", "2017-08-01T02:26:59.000Z")).toDF("id", "eventTime")

df2.withColumn("eventTime1", unix_timestamp($"eventTime", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").cast(TimestampType))
```

Output:

```
+-------------+---------------------+
|userid       |eventTime            |
+-------------+---------------------+
|a3fac        |2017-08-01 02:26:59.0|
+-------------+---------------------+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Suppose we have 9 digits past the decimal, do we really need to specify `ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'`?

Comment: Your format string could read `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"` to parse any timezone, not just UTC

Answer (score 8):

**Solution on Java**

There are some Spark SQL functions which let you to play with the date format.

Conversion example : **20181224091530** -> **2018-12-24 09:15:30**

Solution (Spark SQL statement) :

```
SELECT
 ...
 to_timestamp(cast(DECIMAL_DATE as string),'yyyyMMddHHmmss') as `TIME STAMP DATE`,
 ...
FROM some_table
```

You can use the SQL statements by using an instance of **org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession**. For example if you want to execute an sql statement, Spark provide the following solution:

```
...
// You have to create an instance of SparkSession
sparkSession.sql(sqlStatement); 
...
```

**Notes:**

- You have to convert the decimal to string and after you can achieve the parsing to timestamp format
- You can play with the format the get however format you want...

Comment: My case, used this `to_timestamp(cast(timestamp as string),'yyyyMMddHHmmss')` output coming as null only, where as my timestamp column value is `2019/08/02 15:00:00`. let me know if I am missing anything else.

Answer (score 2):

1. In spark sql you can use  to_timestamp and then format it as your requirement.
   select
   date_format(to_timestamp(,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as 
   from
2. Here 'timestamp' with value is 2019/02/23 12:00:00  and it is StringType column in 'event' table.
   To convert into TimestampType apply to_timestamp(timestamp, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss). It is need to make sure the format for timestamp is same as your column value. Then you apply date_format to convert it as per your requirement.

**> select  date_format(to_timestamp(timestamp,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") as timeStamp from event**