# Spark Scala - convert Timestamp with milliseconds to Timestamp without milliseconds

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp

I have a column in `Timestamp` format that includes milliseconds.

I would like to reformat my `timestamp` column so that it does not include milliseconds.  For example if my Timestamp column has values like **2019-11-20T12:23:13.324+0000**,  I would like my reformatted Timestamp column to have values of  **2019-11-20T12:23:13**

Is there a straight forward way to perform this operation in `spark`-`scala`?  I have found lots of posts on converting string to timestamp but not for changing the format of a `timestamp`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558499/spark-sql-converting-string-to-timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `trunc`.

See more examples: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-date-functions-truncate-date-time/

Comment: Thanks for your post Cesar.  Using date_trunc and "Second" as my measure of time almost gets me there.  However what occurs is that my date goes from 2019-11-20T00:23:00.324+0000  to 2019-11-20T00:23:00.000+0000.   So it just sets all values less than 1 second to 0 rather than dropping those.   I want my timestamp format to drop milliseconds entirely and return "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss"  with no values (even 0) for milliseconds and below.

Comment: Then you are looking for a date format, please check : https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-how-to-convert-date-to-string-format/

Comment: Thanks @Cesar,  that provides the correct datetime without milliseconds but as a string column.  I took that string column and applied every method I could find to convert back to timestamp but in every case conversion re-adds the milliseconds values.   This includes using unix_timestamp,  to_timestamp,   cast(TimestampType).as("timestamp").   Again, thanks for your help, any other suggestions?

Comment: The issue I had with milliseconds, was that if milliseconds were non-zero I could not upload to a database table.  Reformatting using the date_format from your last post in the with column code:  .withColumn("DTTM", date_format(DF("DTTM"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType)) provides the timestamp with zeros for milliseconds+nanoseconds.  While I thought this would still be an issue for transfer, it was not and transfer occurred without error.  Thanks for your help @Cesar!