# Pyspark converting string to UTC timestamp [Getting null]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I am new to pyspark and Spark SQL. I have a dataframe with one column having date time values in string which I need to convert/cast to timestamp.

Dataframe Format:

```
+--------------------+------------------------------+
|               value|                time_from_text|
+--------------------+------------------------------+
|dummy               |2020-04-19T23:49:52.020000453Z|
|dummy               |2020-04-22T23:52:52.020000453Z|
+--------------------+------------------------------+
```

Now, I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558499/spark-sql-converting-string-to-timestamp/45558713) and tried the following code snippet:

```
result.withColumn("Timestamp",unix_timestamp("time_from_text", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS'Z'").cast(TimestampType()))
```

This did work in my earlier case where my spark version was 3.1.1. However, I needed to switch back to 2.4.6 and here, the same code is giving me **null** as the output for the timestamp!

I tried many different ways but am not able to cast the timestamp.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect answer but I found a quick workaround to get the conversion done.
Somehow, the conversion does take place for the format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss". So, I truncated the time_from_text column to lose the sub-seconds accuracy [which is fine for the use case here] and then did the conversion to timestamp.

Code snippet:

```
result = result.withColumn("time_from_text", substring(col("time_from_text"),0,19))
final_result = result.withColumn("Timestamp",unix_timestamp("time_from_text", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").cast(TimestampType())).orderBy("Timestamp")
```

**Reason:**

I did some research and my best guess is that during the upgrading from Spark SQL 3.0 to 3.1, there were some changes done to unix_timestamp codebase. Hence, the format "2020-04-19T23:49:52.020000453Z" is supported in the newer versions but not in the older ones which were implemented via [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) under the hood. Also, the older versions resulted in null for invalid datetime patterns while the newer version will fail directly.

Source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html

Comment: Good investigation :) I leave the code link here just for reference

2.4.6: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.6/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/TimestampFormatter.scala

3.1.1: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.1.1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/util/TimestampFormatter.scala