# Converting a date/time column from binary data type to the date/time data type using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame with date/time column storing data as binary data type. I need to convert it the actual datetime data type so I can run SQL window functions and more. Hence, looking for some working examples.

Input dataframe schema:
root
|-- ce_time: binary (nullable = true)

Sample data:

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |ce_time                                                                              | 
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 |[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 34 3A 33 39 2E 32 30 34 36 37 38 35 5A]|
 |[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 34 3A 34 36 2E 38 32 33 32 34 32 5A]   |
 |[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 34 3A 35 34 2E 34 35 39 30 34 33 37 5A]|
 |[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 35 3A 30 32 2E 35 37 30 38 35 39 36 5A]|
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I can convert the above to string, it looks like this, but I need it in date/time type, not string.

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
 |ce_time                                                                              |ce_time_string              |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
 |[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 34 3A 33 39 2E 32 30 34 36 37 38 35 5A]|2022-05-02T00:04:39.2046785Z|
 |[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 34 3A 34 36 2E 38 32 33 32 34 32 5A]   |2022-05-02T00:04:46.823242Z |
 |[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 34 3A 35 34 2E 34 35 39 30 34 33 37 5A]|2022-05-02T00:04:54.4590437Z|
 |[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 35 3A 30 32 2E 35 37 30 38 35 39 36 5A]|2022-05-02T00:05:02.5708596Z|
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

If someone knows how to convert binary to date/time in PySpark and keep the above date/time values exactly the same, please share!

Much appreciated!!

Comment: have you tried to parse the new string column to timestamp type like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45558713/9477843)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert your binary value to string value using [`decode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.decode.html) built-in function and then convert this string value to timestamp value using [`cast`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.cast.html) column method

*Note: timestamp is spark equivalent of python's datetime type*

Here is the complete code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

result = df.withColumn('ce_time', F.decode('ce_time', 'UTF-8').cast('timestamp'))
```

With the following `df` input dataframe:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ce_time                                                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 34 3A 33 39 2E 32 30 34 36 37 38 35 5A]|
|[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 34 3A 34 36 2E 38 32 33 32 34 32 5A]   |
|[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 34 3A 35 34 2E 34 35 39 30 34 33 37 5A]|
|[32 30 32 32 2D 30 35 2D 30 32 54 30 30 3A 30 35 3A 30 32 2E 35 37 30 38 35 39 36 5A]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You get the following `result` dataframe:

```
+--------------------------+
|ce_time                   |
+--------------------------+
|2022-05-02 02:04:39.204678|
|2022-05-02 02:04:46.823242|
|2022-05-02 02:04:54.459043|
|2022-05-02 02:05:02.570859|
+--------------------------+
```

having the following schema:

```
root
 |-- ce_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```